# Uninstalling VMware workstation in Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Uninstalling VMware workstation in Ubuntu

I have removed some important files of VMware after that I used to uninstall with proper uninstall command of VMware and I'm unable to uninstall VMware workstation

Answer (score 1):

**Uninstalling VMware in Ubuntu machine**

Use command with root permission to uninstall

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

if you removed some files before using above command
the command will not work properly

For this issue:
Reinstall VMware workstation again

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-Full-16.2.4-20089737.x86_64.bundle
```

and use this command again :)

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```